# Multiple insert in database with one transaction id

Tags: php, mysql, database

Is it possible to have one `transaction_id` for multiple inserts in the database? Given that I have a table that has 5 rows.

So I'm able to insert that to the database when I hit submit. But `transaction_id` will be different for every insert. Is there a way around for this? Really new to PHP. And `transaction_id` is an `auto increment`.

Comment: Autoincrement values increment for each row. If you want one per group, you'll have to manage that yourself.

Comment: the whole point of an auto_increment field (which I guess is also your primary key field, probably) is to be unique. Then you have a property which will always identify exactly that row and no other. This is very useful. Now if you want some way to group a set of rows together as having something in common then you can do that separately. Add another column to the table called "groupID" or something and pass a value in for that (the same value for each row) when you run the INSERT.

Comment: If you want to get clever you can define a "groups" table in the DB with another auto_increment field. So you'd first insert a new row into that, then get back the created ID and use that new ID to insert into the groupID field in the original table. And of course groupID would be defined as a foreign key of the ID in the groups table, to ensure integrity. And you'd wrap all your inserts in a SQL Transaction (the technical thing, not your field name) to further ensure integrity. These steps would help to ensure you reliably get a unique, auto-generated group ID each time.

Comment: Can you share some code lines who are you inserting in the table, what are you using mysqli or PDO?

Answer (score 1):

The transaction_id seems to be a primary key and the primary key can't be repeated.
I think one of the possible solutions is to make another column as a foreign key and stores the unique id in another table.
Now the primary keys in transactions will be unique and the column added may be repeated as needed.

Your Schema is going to be like this one:

[image: Your Schema is going to be like this one]